# Sticky boxes with option to close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm very new to web development and might not be using the right terminology, so hopefully I am making sense. I am trying to have sticky boxes that would contain the words a user submitted into a form by pressing Enter. I couldn't find a better example of what I'm trying to achieve than the picture for Plug-In 8 in the link I attached. The boxes I want are in the background, behind the calendar pop-up window. I want to also have an option in the box to close that box (e.g. little "x" icon). The final submission would be when a user clicks a Submit button.

Thanks a lot for any tips

http://tutorialzine.com/2013/04/50-amazing-jquery-plugins/

Comment: Do you have any code you can show to this point? Anything to show the direction you are going beyond the site?

Comment: So, you don't want the calendar ... just the boxes (btw, they are tags)?  If so, clarify it in the question and title, you'll do much better.

Comment: You actually answered my question by asking the follow-up questions. I want exactly what stackoverflow already implemented with their tags above. The answer is here: http://jsfiddle.net/5GD6r/4/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is below. It shows how to add 'sticky' tags to a website (similarly to the ones used by stackoverflow: jsfiddle.net/5GD6r/4